# Inherited interface related cannot convert

Tags: c#

I got following error message:

> Cannot convert from 'RemoteFilesWatcherService' to
>   'IWatcherService'

it raises on following line:

```
var coll = new CollectionService(fileWatcherService);
```

This is my code structure below.

I do not get why i cannot just pass `RemoteFilesWatcherService` into ctor of `CollectionService` as `IWatcherService<IEntity>` since `RemoteFilesWatcherService` implementes `IRemoteFilesWatcherService` which inherits from `IWatcherService<RawDataFile>` so to me it should work.

```
public interface IWatcherService<TDataEntity> where TDataEntity : IEntity
{
    void Watch();
    INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
    ObservableCollection<TDataEntity> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
}


public interface IRemoteFilesWatcherService : IWatcherService<RawDataFile>
{
     IRemoteFilesRepository<IDbManager, RawDataFile> RemoteFilesRepository { get; }
}

public class RemoteFilesWatcherService : IRemoteFilesWatcherService
{
}

class CollectionService
{

    private IWatcherService<IEntity> _watcherService;

    public CollectionService(IWatcherService<IEntity> watcherService)
    {
        _watcherService = watcherService;
    }
}

class Run
{
    void DoIt()
    {
        var fileWatcherService = new RemoteFilesWatcherService();
        var coll = new CollectionService(fileWatcherService);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public interface IDatabaseWatcherService : IWatcherService<DatabaseQuery> 
{
    IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager, DatabaseQuery> DatabaseRepository { get; }
}

public class DatabaseWatcherService : IDatabaseWatcherService
{
    public INotificationFactory NotificationFactory { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<DatabaseQuery> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
    public IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager, DatabaseQuery> DatabaseRepository { get; }


    public DatabaseWatcherService(IDatabaseRepository<IDbManager, DatabaseQuery> databaseRepository)
    {
        DatabaseRepository = databaseRepository;
    }

    public void Watch()
   {
        //first check granurality (time)
        MatchingEntries = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseQuery>(DatabaseRepository.GetQueries());
        if (MatchingEntries.Count == 0) return;
        foreach (var query in MatchingEntries)
            MatchingEntries.Add(query);

        //Database availabiltiy
        //Granurality check
    }      
}
```

Comment: Your `CollectionService` constructor expects an `IWatcherService<IEntity>`, but you're actually passing in an `IWatcherService<RawDataFile>`. Consider what would happen if the constructor called `watcherService.MatchingEntries.Add(new SomeOtherEntity());`. That should be fine for an `IWatcherService<IEntity>`, but wouldn't work with your `RemoteFilesWatcherService`. I suspect your `CollectionService` needs to be generic in the type of entity...

Comment: @Jon Skeet i am not sure  whether it's ok but i changed to: IRemoteFilesWatcherService: IWatcherService<IEntity>. Now it works but am i right thinking that if i continue to say IEntity for IRemoteFilesWatcherService is it fine from technical said? I mean i am thinking like "ok" in that interface i still do not want to precise what exact object it will be, so i can add more additional things inside that interface but i still do not want to precise about IwatcherService<OBJECT>

Comment: Its fine until you need use `RawDataFile` functionality which you will need to cast. i mean there is a lot going on here, and there is little description of what you need it for, which makes it hard to know how to help you other than to say, yes that change will work

Comment: @JonSkeet ok thx for info so it means i can still follow in next derived interfaces, From the other hand (look at my main topic again in EDIT).I have also another class Database IDatabaseWatcherService which inherits from IWatcherService<DatabaseQuery> and then consumer class: DatabaseWatcherService : IDatabaseWatcherService. So that's why either i want to use RemoteFilesWatcherService or DatabaseWatcherService i need to have common for DI therefore since they do not strickly implementing IWatcherService<IEntity> but interfaces as you can see i used IWatcherService<IEntity>.Hope you get point.

Comment: @MichaelRandall The problem is here since  IDatabaseWatcherService : IWatcherService<DatabaseQuery> and public interface IRemoteFilesWatcherService: IWatcherService<IEntity> then if in ctor of Collection i put parameter as IWatcherService<IEntity> only RemoteFilesWatcherService can be putted and not DatabaseWatcherService . How to solve that?

Comment: @MichaelRandall i think i will do:  public interface IDatabaseWatcherService : IWatcherService<IEntity> so IEntity then it will match

Comment: It doesn't really help that you've *only* shown the code, with no explanation of what the intention is. Should a `CollectionService` be able to refer to a `DatabaseWatcherService`? What would it mean for it to do that? Currently we don't know *anything* about the purpose of `CollectionService`. What's its role in your system?

Comment: @JonSkeet how to make collection service as you said generic in my case could you show in answer what you mean? Main reason is collectionservice should be able to get both RemoteFilesWatcherService and DatabaseWatcherService and then use their Matching entries. Therefore i did IwatchService<IEntity> becaus eits common for them both in ctor

Comment: You'd just use `class CollectionService<T> where T : IEntity`, then declare your `_watcherService` with type `IWatcherService<T>`

Comment: @JonSkeet I think i was able to fix, can i share entire code so maybe you could take a look if that makes a sense?

Comment: @Henry: No, I'm afraid I don't have time for that. If it works for you, I expect that's fine - and if it doesn't, it would make sense to edit this question or ask a new one.

Comment: @ok thanks. maybe i go for review forum :)